# Kotlin/Native interoperability with Swift: generated interface with two methods having same signature

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I have a Kotlin multiplatform project which performs Bluetooth operations on iOS devices using the CoreBluetooth library. I am having some problems with getting the peripheral disconnected callback. On closer inspection, I see that the generated `CBCentralManagerDelegateProtocol` interface (which I override) has two methods with same signature.

`@kotlin.commonizer.ObjCCallable public open expect fun centralManager(central: platform.CoreBluetooth.CBCentralManager, didFailToConnectPeripheral: platform.CoreBluetooth.CBPeripheral, error: platform.Foundation.NSError?): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }`

`@kotlin.commonizer.ObjCCallable public open expect fun centralManager(central: platform.CoreBluetooth.CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral: platform.CoreBluetooth.CBPeripheral, error: platform.Foundation.NSError?): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }`

So, I can override only one of these methods. My question is am I missing something here? Like a way to override both the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In kotlin you can't declare two functions with the same signature, differing only by argument names. But in ObjC you can.

To support this interop you can use `@Suppress("CONFLICTING_OVERLOADS")`, as described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#subclassing-swift-objective-c-classes-and-protocols-from-kotlin) in documentation.

> To override different methods with clashing Kotlin signatures, you can add a @Suppress("CONFLICTING_OVERLOADS") annotation to the class.

```kotlin
@Suppress("CONFLICTING_OVERLOADS", "PARAMETER_NAME_CHANGED_ON_OVERRIDE")
override fun centralManager(
    central: CBCentralManager,
    didFailToConnectPeripheral: CBPeripheral,
    error: NSError?
) {
}

@Suppress("CONFLICTING_OVERLOADS", "PARAMETER_NAME_CHANGED_ON_OVERRIDE")
override fun centralManager(
    central: CBCentralManager,
    didDisconnectPeripheral: CBPeripheral,
    error: NSError?
) {
}
```

Comment: I am able to override the two methods and build successfully using your solution. Thank you. However, I am still having issues with the disconnect callback not getting called even when I successfully disconnect. Can you think of a reason why this happens?

Comment: @Anonymous hard to say, generally this technique works to me. Double-check that method signature is correct, kotlin may not warn you if it's not. Try implementing same delegate on the iOS side to see if `didDisconnectPeripheral` is getting called with swift code.